# What causes MetaSearch plugin Search error "Record serialization failed"?

Tags: qgis, metadata, pycsw

I'm trying to use QGIS MetaSearch plugin to search data stored in our pyCSW catalog.
Metasearch will get the correct service info and the GetCapabilities response however, when I try to search the catalog, I get:

`Search error: "Record serialization failed: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'SpatialRepresentationType'"`

Any idea what could be wrong? I'm using the pyCSW server that came with GeoNode.
The catalogue url is http://geoinfo.cnpm.embrapa.br/catalogue/csw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MetaSearch is working fine here and is reporting an exception from the server.  This is an issue with GeoNode which was fixed here: https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/commit/68ce3806327c7478555bf0e64e761df679e2dede

It looks like you are using a version of GeoNode which predates this fix.